# How to connect Sync gate way by the config file?

Tags: couchbase-lite

I have referred the documentation from **couch base server officials**, over there it is given that for connecting **sync gateway** by using `config.json` file use the command

```
$ sync_gateway config.json
```

But  my question is this command is for **windows OS** ? and if not then how should I run sync gateway by using `config.json` file ?

Answer (score 2):

For windows OS

1) Go to command prompt

2) go inside the folder of sync-gateway(where sync gateway .exe is put)

3) Now run the above command as it is